# How to conver the following HTML IE conditionals into Slim?

Tags: slim-lang, html5boilerplate

Can't figure out how to conver the IE conditionals typically seen at the top of an HTML page into Ruby Slim:

```
<!doctype html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7" lang=""> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8" lang=""> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9" lang=""> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang=""> <!--<![endif]-->
```

Anyone know how to do the coversion to Slim?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following fragment should be enough:

```
doctype html
/![if lt IE 7] <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7" lang=""
/![if IE 7] <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8" lang=""
/![if IE 8] <html class="no-js lt-ie9" lang=""
/! [if gt IE 8]><!
html.no-js lang="" 
  /! <![endif]
```

There is a nice tool https://html2slim.herokuapp.com/ that converts HTML into Slim, however it isn't ideal and sometimes do it incorrectly.

Also there is a Ruby gem that you can use for converting HTML files into Slim ones (https://github.com/slim-template/html2slim).